# GCP imports csv successfully from bucket, but database tables are still empty

Tags: mysql, csv, import, google-cloud-platform

I am following this tutorial to import data into cloud SQL:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing

In the "Importing CSV files to Cloud SQL", I follow the steps, and I get the "Import from gs://container/a.csv succeeded." in the "Operations and Logs".

However, when I query my database, the table is still empty.

---

I found the solution. In my case it had to do with foreign key constraint. So the order in which the csv files had to be imported mattered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was using `DESCRIBE <table-name>` to get the order of the properties of my table. I noticed the order was different then the order I had them in the CSV. After changing the columns around to match the order of the output of `DESCRIBE <table-name>` the import worked and the table was populated with the data.